# get a call object, change parameters and run it again with the new parameters

Tags: r, machine-learning, call, dynamically-generated, random-forest

I have a model generated from a random forest. Inside it, there is a attribute called call, that will give me the what was actually the randomForest called function.

I want to get this parameter, remove one column from the model and run it again.

ex:

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species~.-Sepal.Length,  data=iris, prox=TRUE)
iris.rf$call

# want to remove the field Sepal.length as well
# the call should be then 
# randomForest(Species~.-Sepal.Length-Sepal.Width,  data=iris, prox=TRUE)
```

I have tried converting to a list, pasting the new argument and then adding it again to iris.rf[[2]], but it paste in all parts of the formula.

I cannot get rid of the class call, to change it and then call eval() to run it again.

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `parse` on the `paste0` object to get a new expression.  You could then evaluate that new object as a call.

Maybe something like this:

```
> iris.rf$call[[2]][3] <- parse(text = with(iris.rf, {
      paste0(call[[2]][3], " - ", rownames(importance)[1])
  }))
> eval(iris.rf$call)
#
# Call:
#  randomForest(formula = Species ~ . - Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width,      
#               data = iris, prox = TRUE) 
#                Type of random forest: classification
#                      Number of trees: 500
# No. of variables tried at each split: 1
#
#         OOB estimate of  error rate: 3.33%
# Confusion matrix:
#            setosa versicolor virginica class.error
# setosa         50          0         0        0.00
# versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
# virginica       0          2        48        0.04
```

Note that `eval(parse(text = ...))` is not something that is recommended, although it does work nicely for this job.

Comment: Almost there. I want to do it programmatically. The program would get the current columns used and then would remove the least significant one (I have the column name, after ordering the iris.rf$importance).

Comment: @AdrianoAlmeida - see my update, although it may not be ideal

Comment: Yeap, You nailed it. Thanks very much!!

Comment: Oh, nice...  Glad to help. :-)